# Multiple tables displayed in single view mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I have two tables that have a relationship with each other. I would like to be able to view the information simultaneously in a single view. However, when I try to use an attribute from the VolumeRates table I get the error:

> Error  CS1061  'ICollection' does not contain a definition for 'BidRate' and no extension method 'BidRate' accepting a first argument of type 'ICollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) TimberSales C:\Users\kraskell.CDATRIBE2\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\TimberSales\TimberSales\Controllers\DataEntryController.cs    18  Active

The code for my model is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using TimberSales.Models;

namespace TimberSales.Controllers
{
    public class DataEntryController : Controller
    {
        // GET: DataEntry
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            TimberSalesEntities db = new TimberSalesEntities();
            List<TimberSale> timberSales = db.TimberSales.ToList();

            List<DataEntry> dataEntries = timberSales.Select(x => new DataEntry { ContractNumberTimberSales = x.ContractNumber, BidRate = x.VolumesRates.BidRate }).ToList();

            return View(dataEntries);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the `Index.cshtml` file

```
@model IEnumerable<TimberSales.Models.DataEntry>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ContractNumberTimberSales)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BidRate)
        </th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ContractNumberTimberSales)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BidRate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ContractNumberTimberSales }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ContractNumberTimberSales }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ContractNumberTimberSales })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

And this is the `DataEntry` class file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace TimberSales.Models
{
    public class DataEntry
    {
        public string ContractNumberTimberSales { get; set; }
        public string LoggingUnit { get; set; }
        public string TractNumber { get; set; }
        public string Seller { get; set; }
        public string ApprovingOfficer { get; set; }
        public int NumBids { get; set; }
        public decimal TotalTractValue { get; set; }
        public decimal TotalTractVolume { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> AcreageHarvested { get; set; }
        public string SilviculturalTreatment { get; set; }
        public string HarvestReason { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> BidDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> CutPayDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> ContractApprovedDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> ExtensionApprovedDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> ExtensionCuttingEndsDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> ExtentionExpirationDate { get; set; }
        public decimal EstimatedBidValue { get; set; }
        public decimal TotalAmountReceived { get; set; }
        public decimal AdminExpenseDeduction { get; set; }
        public decimal AdminExpenseDeductionPercent { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> SaleClosureDate { get; set; }
        public string Remarks { get; set; }
        public decimal ContractAmount { get; set; }
        public string ContractorName { get; set; }
        public virtual Contractor Contractor { get; set; }

        public int Species { get; set; }
        public int SawProduct { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> EstimatedVolume { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> ActualVolume { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> BaseRate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> AppraisalRate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> AdvertisedRate { get; set; }
        public decimal BidRate { get; set; }
        public string ContractNumberVolumeRates { get; set; }
        public virtual SawProduct SawProduct1 { get; set; }
        public virtual Species Species1 { get; set; }
        public virtual TimberSale TimberSale { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The `TimberSales` object contains a list of `VolumeRates` objects

Do I need to do a `select join` in order to access the information that I need, or can I do this within the `TimberSales.Select` statement to display the information that I need, or do I need to modify `@model IEnumerable<TimberSales.Models.DataEntry>` in the `index.cshtml`?

Comment: What are the VolumeRates? Is that a collection? It's almost as if you need to select down the VolumeRates, such as first or default, then get the BidRate, but I can't say for certain without knowing what the VolumeRates are.

Comment: What is your goal with this line? `List<DataEntry> dataEntries = timberSales.Select(x => new DataEntry { ContractNumberTimberSales = x.ContractNumber, BidRate = x.VolumesRates.BidRate }).ToList();`

Comment: @Radar5000 I would like to be able to view all of the sales that are associated with a contract and ultimately be able to create a new entry

Comment: @SSharp VolumeRates are the sales that have been associated with a contract

Comment: @kevorski Is it a collection? Then you need to do something like a FirstOrDefault().BidRate; on the VolumeRates.

Comment: @SSharp It is a List within the TimberSales object

Comment: Kinda like this, but you need to filter your VolumeRates accordingly: `List<DataEntry> dataEntries = timberSales.Select(x => new DataEntry { ContractNumberTimberSales = x.ContractNumber, BidRate = x.VolumesRates.FirstOrDefault().BidRate }).ToList();`

Comment: @kevorski Where are you getting the contract `ContractNumber` from? I don't see an input variables.

Comment: Contract number comes from the  timber sales object. There is a foreign key relationship between timber sales and volume rates

Comment: @kevorski I understand that their is a relationship but from your words you want to **"view all of the sales that are associated with a contract"**. You need a `ContractNumber` from somewhere to get all the sales, right? Here is an example of what I'm talking about.

`String requestedContract = "[some number]"; //You want to view all the sales that are associated with this ID`

`List<TimberSale> timberSales = db.TimberSales
.Where(x => x.ContractNumberTimberSales = requestedContract)
.ToList();`

Comment: @SSharp This solved it. I realized that I was trying pull the Bid Rate for every single record associated with the contract! Thanks!

Comment: @kevorski I'll add it as an answer. Glad to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, you are trying to push a collection into a BidRate field which is a decimal. You need to collapse the VolumeRates into a single object and then get the BidRate, using FirstOrDefault() or whatever single result you need filtered on:

```
List<DataEntry> dataEntries = timberSales.Select(x => new DataEntry { ContractNumberTimberSales = x.ContractNumber, BidRate = x.VolumesRates.FirstOrDefault().BidRate }).ToList();
```